# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'aws_access_key_id'

Tags: python, amazon-s3, parquet, python-polars

I want to read parquet files in S3 using polars, evidently the following code is working in python 3.9 but not in python 3.7:

```
import polars as pl
storage_options = {
    "aws_access_key_id": access_key,
    "aws_secret_access_key": secret_key,
    "aws_session_token": token
}

lazyframe = pl.scan_parquet(read_path, storage_options=storage_options)
```

error:

```
File "/opt/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 714,
in _iterdir<br>
    await self.set_session()<br>   File "/opt/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 492, in
set_session<br>
    self.session = aiobotocore.session.AioSession(**self.kwargs)<br> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument
'aws_access_key_id'
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the full error traceback message?  It should have started with a line of code from your script.

Comment: Seems polars requires python >= 3.8 https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/py-polars/pyproject.toml#L13

Comment: What versions of the packages are you using? It seems that instead of using the builtin support polars has for S3 it is trying to use fsspec

Comment: This is because of python 3.7, polars using fsspec and s3fs to connect with S3. Upgrading to python3.9